# React Native TypeScript: Unable to resolve module (but it exists)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, node-modules, metro-bundler

I have a fresh React Native 0.61.1 project with TypeScript. It used to display the new project welcome screen perfectly. I've added a class, tried to import it (it even autocompleted), but it says the component could not be found.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` (all the code is in my `src` folder, which is located in my project root):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      // Target latest version of ECMAScript.
      "target": "esnext",
      // Search under node_modules for non-relative imports.
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      // Process & infer types from .js files.
      "allowJs": true,
      // Don't emit; allow Babel to transform files.
      "noEmit": true,
      // Enable strictest settings like strictNullChecks & noImplicitAny.
      "strict": true,
      // Disallow features that require cross-file information for emit.
      "isolatedModules": true,
      // Import non-ES modules as default imports.
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "jsx": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

Notice the `baseUrl` there. It did *not* work before I added it either.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

My `OnboardingScreen.tsx` (which I renamed it from `Onboarding.tsx` *after* screenshotting, so that's not the issue) contains a simple component class with a render method, exported as default.

Here is my `App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import OnboardingScreen from 'views/screens/OnboardingScreen';

const App: () => React.ReactNode = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <OnboardingScreen/>
    </>
  );
};


export default App;
```

When I type `Onbo...` it even completes the import by itself. But when I run the app I get the infamous error:

```
Unable to resolve module `views/screens/OnboardingScreen` from `src/App.tsx`: views/screens/OnboardingScreen could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

Before you ask: Yes, after each try I do all of the above and even restart Vscode.

I've also tried adding the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
 "paths": {
    "views/*":["src/views/*"]
 }
```

Though nothing changed either. What am I doing wrong? (I'm on TypeScript 3.6.2)

**UPDATE:** Apparently, `paths` is completely ignored but if I put a `package.json` file into each root folder that I want to reference with imports (e.g. `components` folder), it is picked up. For example I put the following `package.json` into `components`:

```
{
    "name": "components"
}
```

Then my code can reference it. Though, I still have no idea why it doesn't work with `tsconfig` `path`.

Comment: Did you try `'./views/screens/OnboardingScreen'` ??

Comment: @hongdevelop just tried it and apparently it works that way. but I don't wanna use relative paths, I want to use it as `views/screens/OnboardingScreen` from anywhere within the app.

Comment: try replacing  `"baseUrl": "src"` with `"baseUrl": ".",` in your tsconfig.json file

Comment: @AbhaySharma but my base URL isn't root, it's `src` 

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'd like to use absolute imports

Comment: But thank you for finding that package.json trick!

Comment: yes... using relative paths does the job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One path to resolve this error is:

Add a package.json file with the content: `{"name": "@services"}` in `views` folder.

The import must be `import OnboardingScreen from '@views/screens/OnboardingScreen';`

React-native and TypeScript use individual methods to find files with absolute paths. This way fix this error to me :)

Comment: Yeah, I went exactly that way :)

Comment: how did you found out this method?  is it in react native's doc or something?

Comment: How does this work if `@services` and `@views` don't match? Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

you can install `babel-plugin-module-resolver`

```bash
yarn add babel-plugin-module-resolver 
# or 
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

And

setting `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          '^views/(.+)': './src/views/\\1',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "views/*": ["views/*"]
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you!. This is the only combination that works. **** you metro/babel .